# Update Button in Android after object value changes?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have an array that stores objects of type Cup. The button displays the value of numberOfPebbles in the cup. Clicking the button causes all the buttons to increase by 1 - this i have logged in logcat and the array updates but I can't get the button to update with the new array value when using the emulator. Here is my code:Bare in mind they are in separate classes

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setText(move.cups.get(0).toString());
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        move.makeMove(move.cups.get(0));
    }
});

public List<Cup> cups;
public List<Integer> cupValues;

public void newGame(){

    cups = new ArrayList<>();
    cupValues = new ArrayList<>();

    //Reset all cups and values
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        Cup cup = new Cup(7);
        cups.add(i, cup);
        Log.d("Move.java", "Printing array valuess:" + cups.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Whay don't you add a field for `Cup` value to your `Cup` class instead of keeping an other array for `Cup` values?

Comment: Your not using `capValues` already :)

Comment: "The button" Which button? "all the buttons" How many do you have? Can you show us your design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the button's text each time a click occurs

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setText(move.cups.get(0).toString());
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        move.makeMove(move.cups.get(0));
        button1.setText(move.cups.get(0).toString()); //or whatever you want to display in the button after each click
    }
});
```